# Why must files be entirely rewritten when there are arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, file, io, fwrite

From what I've read on the internet and in books, when editing a text file, or any file for that matter, the file must be entirely rewritten; You can't just insert data into a file and save it.

If this is so, how can there be arrays in programming languages? In C++ I can explicitly modify certain values in the middle of arrays. To me, this seems like a demonstration of the modification of one or two bytes in the middle of a group of bytes.

The only two possible solutions I have thought of are

- There is some funky stuff going on behind-the-scenes in C++, so it seems like only one or two bytes are being modified, but the array is actually entirely rewritten.
- Then, after thinking about it, and especially after typing it out, I realized the the aformentioned solution seems really *really* dumb and totally not true, because there are things like addresses and pointers and the performance sounds awful. So I thought that maybe files are not entirely rewritten; only the everything after the first point in new data was inserted is rewritten. This seems much more plausible to me, and makes sense.

What is the difference between writing data to a file and writing data to an array?

Comment: You are simply misinterpreting what you have read on the internet. You can change a byte in the middle of a file. You cannot *insert* a new byte in the middle of a file (or an array) without touching the rest.

Comment: @n.m. "without touch the rest" - more precisely, without touching the data between the point of insertion and the end of the file or array.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the values of particular locations in an array without needing to re-write the whole thing.  However, you cannot insert new values into the middle of an array without shifting everything following the new values in order to make room.

Similarly, you can overwrite sections of a file without copying it (although the underlying storage technology may need to re-write an entire storage block in order to change a single byte within that block), but you can't insert new data without somehow making room for it.  Text editors (and editors for more complicated file formats) are designed for random-access modifications that do not preserve length, so they will typically re-write the entire file regardless of what changed rather than trying to optimize for length-preserving edits.